# System variable change doesn't work

Tags: server, mysql

I'm going to change a system variable in mysql by:

```
mysql -u root -e "set collation_connection=utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
```

but when i call the following command it is not changed:

```
mysql -u root -e "select @@collation_connection"
```

I even restart the mysql service but it doesn't work.

Comment: which version of Ubuntu? Note that root stuff has changed for 18.04 (but I do not know if what you are attempting to do has changed or not).

Comment: @DougSmythies, ubuntu 18

Comment: I'm not sure, so not doing this as an answer. Try `sudo mysql -e "set collation_connection=utf8mb4_unicode_ci"` and `sudo mysql -e "select @@collation_connection"`

Comment: @DougSmythies, I tried the same but doesn't work

Comment: O.K. sorry for the distraction. For reference [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1752215) is what I was thinking of.